# Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to create a class Room that simulates a hospital room but it keeps giving me an error in my constructor.  Sometimes there's no issue but then it comes back....other user defined objects here include a Patient class that has no problems and a LinkedList template class that also has no issues.

Here's the header

```
class Room
{
public:

    Room();
    Room(int);
    static LinkedList<Room> createRooms();

    Patient patient;
    int roomNumber;

    bool operator==(const Room &other) const; //overload ==
    bool operator!=(const Room &other) const; //overload !=
    void operator=(const Room &other) const; //overload =



};
```

and the cpp

```
#include "Room.h"

Room::Room();
Room::Room(int n)
{
    roomNumber= n;
    patient= Patient();
}
LinkedList<Room> Room::createRooms() {
    //create rooms up until ROOMS is reached
    LinkedList<Room> roomList;
    for(int i= 1; i < 11; i++){
        Room room= Room(100+i);
        roomList.push(room);
    }
    return roomList;

}
//Overload ==
bool Room::operator==(const Room &other)const{
    //compare each room's room number field
    return (this->roomNumber == other.roomNumber && this->patient == other.patient);

}
//Overload !=
bool Room::operator!=(const Room &other)const{
    return !(this == &other);
}

void Room::operator=(const Room &other)const{
    this->patient= other.patient;
    this->roomNumber= other.roomNumber;
}
```

the problem is with the Room(int) constructor.  Xcode keeps giving me a message saying Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

I have no idea what's going on

Comment: Please post the exact code and exact error messages.

Comment: The error message may be referring to `Room::Room();`  , this is illegal, `Room::Room` must be followed by either a ctor-initializer list, or `{`

Answer (score 3):

You clearly forgot to include the header that defines `Patient`:

```
 #include "Patient.h"
```

or similar.

Also,

```
patient= Patient();
```

is redundant, the member `patient` will be value-initialized by default, and

```
Room::Room();
```

is not correct - you're not providing an implementation.

Next, **your design seems flawed**. You seem to imply that a patient is part of a room, and chose composition to do so. But it's not. What if the room is empty? Your current design doesn't yet treat that case.

EDIT: did you mean:

```
return !(*this == other);
```

in your overload to `operator!=`?

Comment: should I include the header or the cpp for patient?

Comment: @user1864287 in this case, in the header because you're using a member of type `Patient` in the header. However, I suggest you change the design.

Comment: I changed the Room::Room(); already and its a precondition that every room has a patient

Answer (score 0):

This looks weird:

```
   Room::Room();
```

I think you want this:

```
   Room::Room() {}
```

You should probably at least initialize the member variables however instead of having a blank constructor.

Comment: Yeah I had fixed that before

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to change the following constructor to "explicit" in the header (never abuse "explicit" but sometime is needed)

```
explicit Room(int);
```

What if there are in your code places where a class accept both "int" or "const Room&" as constructor parameters?

Assume:

```
Hospital(int n); //Hospital constructor where n is number of rooms
Hospital(const Room& room); //Hospital constructor, hosptial made initially by only 1 room
```

In this case without a explicit constructor

```
Hospital sanGrace(3);
```

the compiler can't tell if you intented

```
Hospital sanGrace(3);
```

or

```
Hospital sanGrace(Room(3));
```

with "explicit" you are forced to write

```
Hospital sanGrace(Room(3));
```

if you want to create SanGrace's Hospital from a room with number 3.

The same applies also for Patient class.